# A question related to harmonic numbers

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, harmonic-numbers

For $n \geq 1$ fixed, I want to know how to compute the double sum

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^n \frac{1}{i \cdot j}.
\end{equation}

In particular, can we say anything about the order of this sum in terms of n ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

if you set 
$$
s_n= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{k^2} \\
h_n= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{k}
$$
then
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^n \frac{1}{i \cdot j} = \frac12 \left( h_n^2 - s_n \right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

First change order of summation:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}\frac{1}{ij}=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n-j}\frac{1}{i(j+i)}$$

Now for fixed $j$ we can compute $\sum_{i=1}^{n-j}\frac{1}{i(j+i)}$:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-j}\frac{1}{i(j+i)}=\sum_{i=1}^{n-j}\frac{1}{j}\left(\frac{1}{i}-\frac{1}{j+i}\right)=\frac{1}{j}\sum_{i=1}^{n-j}\left(\frac{1}{i}-\frac{1}{j+i}\right)=\frac{1}{j}(H_{n-j}-(H_{n}-H_{j-1}))=\frac{1}{j}\left(-H_{n}+H_{n-j}+H_{j-1}\right)$$

So:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n-j}\frac{1}{i(j+i)}=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{j}\left(-H_{n}+H_{n-j}+H_{j-1}\right)=-H_nH_{n-1}+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{j}\left(H_{n-j}+H_{j-1}\right)=\\=-\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n-j}\frac{1}{i(j+i)}+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{j}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{j}\frac{1}{i}-\frac{1}{j}\right)=\\=-\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n-j}\frac{1}{i(j+i)}+H_n^2-\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{j^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\tt\mbox{Note that}}$:

\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{i\ =\ 1}^{n - 1}\sum_{j\ =\ i + 1}^{n}%
{1 \over i\,j}}
=\sum_{i\ =\ 1}^{n - 1}{1 \over i}
\pars{\sum_{j\ =\  1}^{n}{1 \over j} - \sum_{j\ =\  1}^{i}{1 \over j}}
=\sum_{i\ =\ 1}^{n - 1}{1 \over i}\pars{H_{n} - H_{i}}
=H_{n - 1}H_{n} - \color{#c00000}{%
\sum_{i\ =\ 1}^{n - 1}{H_{i} \over i}}\,\,\,\pars{1}
\end{align}

> However
>   \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{\sum_{i\ =\ 1}^{n - 1}{H_{i} \over i}}
> =\sum_{i\ =\ 1}^{n - 1}{1 \over i}\int_{0}^{1}{1 - t^{i} \over 1 - t}\,\dd t
> =\sum_{i\ =\ 1}^{n - 1}{1 \over i}
> \int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{1 - t}\pars{-i\,t^{i - 1}}\,\dd t
> \\[5mm]&=-\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{1 - t}\sum_{i\ =\ 1}^{n - 1}t^{i - 1}\,\dd t
> =-\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{1 - t}\,{1 - t^{n - 1} \over 1 - t}\,\dd t
> \\[5mm]&=\int_{t\ =\ 0}^{t\ =\ 1}\pars{1 - t^{n - 1}}\,
> \dd\bracks{\ln^{2}\pars{1 - t}}
> =\pars{n - 1}\int_{0}^{1}t^{n - 2}\ln^{2}\pars{1 - t}\,\dd t
> \\[5mm]&=\pars{n - 1}\lim_{\mu\ \to\ 0}\partiald[2]{}{\mu}
> \int_{0}^{1}t^{n - 2}\pars{1 - t}^{\mu}\,\dd t
> =\pars{n - 1}\lim_{\mu\ \to\ 0}\partiald[2]{}{\mu}\bracks{%
> \Gamma\pars{n - 1}\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{n + \mu}}
> \\[5mm]&=\pars{n - 1}!\lim_{\mu\ \to\ 0}\partiald[2]{}{\mu}\bracks{%
> \Gamma\pars{\mu + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{n + \mu}}
> =\Psi^{2}\pars{n} + 2\gamma\Psi\pars{n} - \Psi'\pars{n} + \zeta\pars{2} + \gamma^{2}
> \end{align}

Replacing in $\pars{1}$:
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{i\ =\ 1}^{n - 1}\sum_{j\ =\ i + 1}^{n}%
{1 \over i\,j}}
=\color{#66f}{\large H_{n - 1}H_{n}
-\Psi^{2}\pars{n} - 2\gamma\Psi\pars{n} + \Psi'\pars{n} - \zeta\pars{2} - \gamma^{2}}
\end{align}